# ¿Cómo obtener el id de usuario con Facebook SDK para .NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook, facebook-api

Estoy utilizando Facebook SDK para .NET 7.0.6

Con éste código puedo obtener nombre, apellido y otros atributos, pero no el id del usuario.

```
    var _fb = new FacebookClient(Session["FbuserToken"].ToString());
    dynamic resultMe = _fb.Get("me?fields=id");
    return resultMe.id;
```

¿Cómo puedo obtenerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Esto no sólo sucede en el SDK .NET. En general, Facebook se toma bastantes molestias para evitar que a través del API de derive el FBID numérico de un usuario, a partir de el username u otros datos como. Nombres y apellidos.

La solución usualmente es derivarlo a través de las mismas URL que FB genera como respuestas a otras consultas, (scraping)